# Use of absolutePan() to move background image and elements around on canvas with touch event

Tags: javascript

I am using next code to force content of canvas to follow finger touch movement on screen (drag and drop).

```
document.addEventListener('touchmove', function(e){

if(e.targetTouches.length ==1) {

          var canavasMovex=e.targetTouches[0].pageX-canvasLeftofset-canvas.width/2;
          var canavasMovey=e.targetTouches[0].pageY-canvasTopofset-canvas.height/2;
          document.getElementById("a").innerHTML=  canavasMovex;
          document.getElementById("b").innerHTML= canavasMovey;

        var delta = new fabric.Point(-canavasMovex,-canavasMovey);
        canvas.absolutePan(delta);            
     canvas.renderAll();                     
  }    
}, false);
```

Note: "-canavasMovex,-canavasMovey" values have the negative sign (I had to use it because otherwise the canvas was moving opposite to finger moment(I think you can ignore this fact and that it has noting to do with offset, which I am trying to solve asking for help here))

I have displacement of position proportional to the distance of touch point from the centre of canvas. If I start the movement pressing from the centre of screen, then displacement is not so notable. But if I start from  top corner (for example) I get centre of canvas there in that touch point. From attached drawing I was trying with taking of consideration of "d" parameter (distance of touching point to the centre of canvas), to find right value for the equation for the canvas.absolutePan() function, but no success. Can you help me with this case,pleas? I was trying to use some solutions from browsing the internet to find the way to move canvas content. But then I had lost some of functions of my app because "new" libraries were not interacting correctly with my existing fabric.min.js library. Image info(external rectangle-web page,internal rectangle-canvas):  a-canvas offset,b-distance to centre of canvas,c- touch point,d-distance from touch point to centre of canvas. So on the end I am trying to get to accomplish this task in this way.

Malfunction:
Bigger than distance "d" is on starting of dragging , bigger is then the offset. (actuary if I start dragging from canvas corner, canvas content transfers its centre there)

[image]

Comment: Lets presume that on canvas I have background image of 10 X 10 numbers matrix and some other shapes (they are not part of this code). Each time I start the dragging canvas around, it's content jumps to have number 23 (matrix 10 X 10) under my finger. So also even when I had moved already my canvas content, next time when begin to drag again I get the same situation. Position of canvas image where number 23 is jumps under the finger.
I would like to achieve that whichever point on canvas I press as start of dragging, the movement has to start from there.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to get the finger position, calculate the difference to previous position, add difference to the previous position and then finally do the panning.

```
 var canvasMovexoold = 0;
 var canvasMoveyoold = 0;

document.addEventListener('touchstart', function(e){
    canvasMovexoold = canvasLeftofset+canvas.width/2-e.targetTouches[0].pageX;
    canvasMoveyoold =canvasTopofset+canvas.height/2- e.targetTouches[0].pageY;
}, false);

document.addEventListener('touchmove', function(e){

 if(e.targetTouches.length ==1) {
      var  canvasMovexo += canvasLeftofset+canvas.width/2-e.targetTouches[0].pageX-canvasMovexoold ;
      var  canvasMoveyo +=canvasTopofset+canvas.height/2- e.targetTouches[0].pageY-canvasMoveyoold ;
      var delta = new fabric.Point(canvasMovexo,canvasMoveyo); 
      canvas.absolutePan(delta); 
      canvasMovexoold = canvasLeftofset+canvas.width/2-e.targetTouches[0].pageX;
      canvasMoveyoold =canvasTopofset+canvas.height/2- e.targetTouches[0].pageY;
   }
}, false);
```